# Is there any IDEs or plugins for developing ABNF grammars?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, abnf

I am currently debugging an ABNF grammar. It is currently very big. I am finding it difficult to debug. An IDE or syntax highlighter would be very helpful.

Is there any recommended ABNF grammar IDE or plugin available? Not the BNF ides and plugins.  My online research gave me only the BNF plugins which don't recognise ABNF syntax like the slant operator.

Comment: Have you found anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need and have not found an answer.  However, I find Lark (https://github.com/lark-parser/lark) very easy to use.

As a workaround, I am developing in Lark's EBNF-derived grammar language. Once the parser is working, hand-translating the Lark grammar to ABNF is relatively straightforward.  Unfortunately even ABNF parsers are in short supply, so it's not possible to check the translation for functional correctness.  I settle for syntactic correctness using https://tools.ietf.org/tools/bap/abnf.cgi.

If anyone else knows of a Python parser that uses ABNF, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Just FYI, there is an open issue to support ABNF in Lark: https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/issues/318
Perhaps a show of support will encourage the contributors to work faster :)